# if shell command empty

Tags: shell

`if pgrep apache; then echo "oliver"; fi`
This will echo `oliver` if the command `pgrep apache` is not empty. I want to do the reverse. If the the command `pgrep apache` returns an empty string, run a command.

Comment: The echo does not happen because '`pgrep apache` is not empty'.  Rather, it is executed because `pgrep` returns successfully.  In this case, the command being successful and the command generating some output are equivalent,  but this is a common source of confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if ! pgrep apache; then echo "oliver"; fi
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks DigitalRoss.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this :

```
pgrep &>/dev/null apache || echo "foobar"
```

or :

```
if ! pgrep &>/dev/null apache; then echo "foobar"; fi
```

`!` stands for *NOT*

this is not based on the output of the command but if the command whas `true` or `false`.

In [shell](/questions/tagged/shell), when the return code of a command is `0`, it's considered `true`, if more than 0, it's `false`. You can check this return code with the variable `$?`, example :

```
ls /path/to/inexistant/file
echo $?
```

See [true & false commands](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_and_false_%28commands%29)

Comment: Do *not* use `&>`.  The grammar is ambiguous: `bash` will treat it the same as `>/dev/null 2>&1`, while `dash` will treat it as `& >` (it will run the process in the backround, and then truncate `/dev/null`)

Answer (score 1):

I'm unsure of the context but presuming you want to do something a particular process is or is not found.

```
bash-3.2$ pgrep -q bash &&  echo "bash was found"
bash was found

bash-3.2$ pgrep -q XXXbash ||  echo "XXXbash was NOT was found"
XXXbash was NOT was found
```